# How does the trait upcast coercion workaround work (trait method for getting an instance of the supertrait)?

Tags: rust, traits

It looks like Rust does not allow using a reference to an instance of a trait to be used where a reference to an instance of the supertrait was expected:

```rs
trait Animal{}
trait Dog: Animal{}

fn convert(dog: &Dog) -> &Animal {
    dog // Error: trait upcasting coercion is experimental, see issue #65991 ...
}
```

But there's a workaround, used often in [the Rust-Analyzer codebase](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/blob/75b22326dad1914c22484ab6672de5cae94f7457/crates/base-db/src/lib.rs#L36). **How does the workaround work?**

Here's the workaround, which enables us to write a `convert` that `rustc` will accept:

```
trait Animal{}
trait Dog: Animal{
    fn upcast(&self) -> &Animal; // added line
}
fn convert(dog: &Dog) -> &Animal {
    dog.upcast() // changed line
}
```

And here's an implementation of `upcast`:

```
struct Foo {}
impl Animal for Foo {}
impl Dog for Foo {
    fn upcast(&self) -> &Animal {
        self
    }
}
```

Comparing the `upcast` and the original `convert`: they have the same signature and same implementation (modulo renaming). So it looks like something is allowed for methods that is not allowed for functions. What happened?

Comment: A method knows the full type of the struct it implemented on (here `Foo`). A function only knows what it's told in its declaration (here `dyn Dog`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&self` in `upcast()` is not `&dyn Dog`, it is the concrete `&Foo`. This is usual call to a method of a `dyn Trait`.